# C++ - Implementation of class methods/voids

Tags: c++, class, methods, void

I'm currently learning SDL for creating graphical applications/games in C++ and have a few questions about how you create and use voids within classes.

For my current project I'm creating a very basic pong game and would like to create a class that not only contains information about an object's position, loaded bitmap and other variables but also a function that covers the AI/Movement Engine and another for the rendering.

I would like to code it so that I could format my code like this:
(All code below is pseudo code and only represents the structure of what I want to achieve)

```
class Object
{
    private int stuff;
    private void manageStuff();
}

void Object::manageStuff()
{
    stuff++;
}

Object object = new Object();

object.stuff = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
{
    object.manageStuff();
    cout << object.stuff;
}
```

Are there any obvious ways of doing this in C++?

Comment: There are a number of problems with that code, but it's all "close" to correct C++.  Have you tried compiling a program?  Are you stuck or confused by anything specific?

Comment: Not really sure what the question is really, seems like basic C++ to me. You have a few syntax errors that make it seem like you are more used to Java. Are you asking for help to fix the syntax errors? Or is a more general design question?

Comment: It's all pseudo-code, and also I'm surprised that it looks like Java seeing as I have never programmed in it :) the main bit I'm confused with is the syntax of creating a void that will only change the variable of it's constructor class even though the variable in the void will always be the same, so if there are 2 of Object, then running the method on object1 wont affect the variable in object2 despite the variable name in the void being hard-coded

Comment: You mention "use voids".  Are you talking about having a void return type for a method?

Comment: I think you're confusing the return type of a function/method with it's language name. Don't say voids like that say member function or method.

Comment: @TotalJargon You don't need to worry, your 'void' will behave exactly as you want it to.

Comment: C# is very similar to Java which is probably why @jahhaj made that observation. I strongly suggest you sit down with a C++ textbook if this is the language you wish to use for this project. Your terminology isn't accurate in your question. It will also help you post more correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for constructors and initalizer lists. There are a number of other issues in the example you showed too, which I've fixed and commented in place. Perhaps:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
// Note: access modifier written like this:
public:
    int stuff;
    void manageStuff();
    Object(); // Constructor which takes no arguments
}; // note semicolon

void Object::manageStuff()
{
    stuff++;
}

Object::Object() : stuff(0) {
  // sets stuff to 0 upon initalization.  
  // could also have written:
  // stuff=0;
  // but in this case initalization is nicer.
}

Object object; // no need for new here

// initial value of stuff set via constructor now,
// you can't just write random statements anywhere

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // note semicolon not comma
  {
      // if these were private this would fail:
      object.manageStuff();
      std::cout << object.stuff << "\n"; 
  }
}
```

Is more like what you were looking for.

Comment: That's great thank you! works just as I needed ^^ now if I alter that code to have object1 and object2 and have manageStuff() work independantly! :D (not sure if your IDE/Comiler allows but you can add 'using namespace::std' to remove the need for std:: in front of many functions like cout)

Comment: @TotalJargon I use emacs and I can type whatever I like, but I usually [deliberately avoid `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you wish to use C++, you will have to actually learn C++. This involves, at least, learning C++'s syntax. Trying to force it to emulate the syntax of another language is not going to be possible or beneficial.

Comment: Sorry about the badly written code, was slightly rushed so I missed silly things like new being used in VC# not C++